# Problems on deploy of Docker with Go

Tags: docker, web-services, dockerfile

I'm trying to deploy an application in golang with docker.

I've tried `docker build -t go-k8s .` then `docker run -it {{image-id}}`

```
# build stage
FROM golang:latest AS builder
RUN mkdir -p /go/src/app
RUN go get github.com/gorilla/mux
WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY main.go .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o main .

# final stage
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=builder /go/src/app .
CMD ["./main"]
```

Go App:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func IndexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "Yay, it works!\nWelcome to Leroy Merlin SRE / DevOps Engineer Test App :)")
}

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/", IndexHandler).Methods("GET")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":1337", router))
}
```

Could anyone please tell me where is my mistake, because the build happens anyway, but docker run didn't do anything.

Comment: What specifically is your question/problem?

Comment: What is your question? If there is an error message, please provide that and explain.

Answer (score 0):

You are not publishing the port used by the webserver in the container. Instead, do something like

```
docker run -p 1337:1337 go-k8s
```

after building. At this point, you should be able to access your service from the host:

```
$ curl localhost:1337
Yay, it works!
Welcome to Leroy Merlin SRE / DevOps Engineer Test App :)
```